# Finding a sum of $1+\frac{1}{4\cdot2^{4}}+\frac{1}{7\cdot2^{7}}+\frac{1}{10\cdot2^{10}}+\cdots$

Tags: integration, derivatives, summation

I need someone to find a mistake in my soliution or maybe to solf it much more easily... I have got a sum $$1+\frac{1}{4\cdot2^{4}}+\frac{1}{7\cdot2^{7}}+\frac{1}{10\cdot2^{10}}+\cdots$$ and need to evaluate it. So here's my soliution:
$$S(x)=1+\frac{x^{4}}{4\cdot2^{4}}+\frac{x^{7}}{7\cdot2^{7}}+\frac{x^{10}}{10\cdot2^{10}}+\cdots=1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{3n+1}}{(3n+1)\cdot2^{3n+1}}=1+S_1(x)$$
$$(S_1(x))_x'=\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{3n+1}}{(3n+1)\cdot2^{3n+1}}\right)_x'=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{3n}}{2^{3n+1}}=\frac{1}{x}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{3n+1}$$
Now let's take $\frac{x}{2}=y$, then
$$S_2(y)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty y^{3n+1}=y^4+y^7+y^{10}+\cdots=\frac{y^4}{1+y^3},|y|\le1$$
$$\left(S_1(y)\right)'=\frac{1}{2y}\cdot\frac{y^4}{1-y^3}=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{y^3}{1-y^3}$$
$$S_1(y)=\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{y^3}{1-y^3}dy=\frac{1}{2}\int\left(-1+\frac{1}{1-y^3}\right)dy=-\frac{1}{2}y+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{6}\arctan\left(\frac{2\left(y+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{3}}\right)+\frac{1}{12}\ln\left|\left(y+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\frac{3}{4}\right|-\frac{1}{6}\ln\lvert y-1\rvert+C$$

$$S_1(x)=-\frac{1}{4}x+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{6}\arctan\left(\frac{x+1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)+\frac{1}{12}\ln\left|\left(\frac{x}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\frac{3}{4}\right|-\frac{1}{6}\ln\left|\frac{x}{2}-1\right|+C$$
$$S_1(0)=0, C=-\frac{\sqrt{3}\pi}{36}$$
$$S(x)=-\frac{1}{4}x+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{6}\arctan\left(\frac{x+1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)+\frac{1}{12}\ln\left|\left(\frac{x}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\frac{3}{4}\right|-\frac{1}{6}\ln\left|\frac{x}{2}-1\right|-\frac{\sqrt{3}\pi}{36}+1$$
$$S(1)=\frac{3}{4}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}\arctan\left(\frac{2\sqrt{3}}{3}\right)+\frac{1}{6}\ln(7)-\frac{\sqrt{3}\pi}{36}$$
By writing this for about 2 hours I deserve extra 50 points or at least good answers... Ha ha, thanks!

Comment: 5 points granted :P

Comment: Well thank you, @TheDeadLegend :D

Comment: As I see it, $(S_1(y))' = \frac{1}{2y} S_2(y) $, however your denominators are different in the two expressions

Comment: One tip: You could saved some algebra by anticipating the substitution $y=x/2$ and taken your terms to be $x^{3n+1}/(3n+1)$ right from the get-go (evaluating at $x=1/2$ rather than $x=1$ at the very end.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's worth cleaning things up a bit:

$$1+{1\over4\cdot2^4}+{1\over7\cdot2^7}+{1\over10\cdot2^{10}}+\cdots={1\over2}+{1\over2}\left(1+{1\over4\cdot2^3}+{1\over7\cdot2^6}+{1\over10\cdot2^9}+\cdots \right)\\={1\over2}+{1\over2}f(1)$$

where

$$f(x)=x+{x^4\over4\cdot2^3}+{x^7\over7\cdot2^6}+{x^{10}\over10\cdot2^9}+\cdots$$

Now

$$f'(x)=1+{x^3\over2^3}+{x^6\over2^6}+{x^9\over2^9}+\cdots={1\over1-\left(x\over2\right)^3}={8\over8-x^3}$$

Since $f(0)=0$, we have

$$1+{1\over4\cdot2^4}+{1\over7\cdot2^7}+{1\over10\cdot2^{10}}+\cdots={1\over2}+{1\over2}\int_0^1f'(x)dx={1\over2}+\int_0^1{4\over8-x^3}dx$$

Patient partial fractions gives

$$\int_0^1{4\over8-x^3}dx={1\over\sqrt3}\left(\arctan\left(2\over\sqrt3\right)-{\pi\over6}\right)+{1\over6}\ln7$$

and thus

$$1+{1\over4\cdot2^4}+{1\over7\cdot2^7}+{1\over10\cdot2^{10}}+\cdots={1\over2}+{\sqrt3\over3}\arctan\left(2\sqrt3\over3\right)+{1\over6}\ln7-{\pi\sqrt3\over18}\\
\approx1.016849$$

Remark:  The OP's result has $3/4$ instead of $1/2$ and $\pi\sqrt3/36$ instead of $\pi\sqrt3/18$.  Numerically it gives $1.417999...$, which is clearly too large.

Answer (score 4):

To apply a [discrete Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform) to Taylor series of $-\log(1-x)$ is a good idea.
Since 
$$ -\log(1-x)=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{x^n}{n} $$
we have
$$ \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{x^{3n+1}}{3n+1} = \int_{0}^{x}\frac{dt}{1-t^3}\\= -\frac{1}{3}\log(1-x)+\frac{1}{18} \left(-\sqrt{3} \pi +6 \sqrt{3} \arctan\left(\frac{1+2 x}{\sqrt{3}}\right)+3 \log\left(1+x+x^2\right)\right) $$
and by evaluating at $x=\frac{1}{2}$ it follows that
$$ \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{(3n+1)2^{3n+1}}=\frac{1}{2}\,\phantom{}_2 F_1\left(\frac{1}{3},1;\frac{4}{3};\frac{1}{8}\right)= \color{red}{\frac{1}{18} \left[-\pi\sqrt{3}+6 \sqrt{3} \arcsin\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt 7}\right)+3 \log(7)\right]}$$

Comment: Sorry, but your answer is incorrect as well. You get too less. Just put this sum into wolfram alpha and you'll see the answer is 1,008 and so on, I don't remember by myself.

Comment: @JonasVitkauskas: what I wrote is correct. It is not OP's original series, of course, since the first term is different, but it is straightforward to manipulate to get what is needed.

Comment: To match the pattern the first term of OP's series should be $\frac{1}{1\cdot 2^1}\neq 1$, and that is what I dealt with in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Similar to the answer by Jack D'Aurizio and yours, but let $$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{3n+1}\cdot x^{3n+1}\implies f'(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{3n} =\frac{1}{1-x^3}$$ 
Hence, 
$$f(x) = \int\frac{1}{1-x^3}dx = \frac{1}{6}\left(\ln(x^2+x+1)-2\ln(1-x)+2\sqrt{3}\arctan\left(\frac{2x+1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)\right)+C$$ Because $f(0)=0$ we have $C = -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{18}\pi$. We get our result by noticing that our result is $\frac{1}{2}+f\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$, which is approximately $1.016849...$.

Comment: Sorry, but the answer is incorrect. :/ You get too much

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out! I fixed the error, which was because the first term in $f(x)$ is not $1$.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes when faced by one of these "sections" of a well-known series it helps to think "roots of unity". The other solutions given here are surely the way to go in this case, but it's worth knowing the generic technique, so here goes.

Let $G(x)=\sum_0^\infty \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}$ we see that we want "one-third" of this series. So with $\omega:=\exp{\frac{2\pi}{3}}$ we have that the given series is the value at $x=\frac{1}{2}$ of
$$\frac{1}{3}\left[G(x)+\omega^2\ G(\omega x)+ \omega\ G(\omega^2 x)\right].$$ 
We'd get a couple of other series by taking the other obvious multipliers, $(1,1,1)$ and $(1,\omega,\omega^2)$.

As $G(x)=\log (1-x)$ there's then nothing left to do apart from some tedious arithmetic evaluating the modulus and argument of things like $1-\frac{1}{2}\omega$.